# how can I count the number of a letter in each section

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a data like this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
```

I am trying to get the number of K in each section , so the output I am trying to get is like this

```
         K    R
Q96A73   7    11   
P13674   17   13
Q7Z4N8   11   11
P04637   2    4
```

I have been trying to do it using

```
cat mydata.txt | grep -v '^>' | grep -i -e [k] |wc -l
```

so for example if we look at the first one

```
          K    R    KK   RR
Q96A73   7    11    0      0
P13674   17   13    1     2
Q7Z4N8   11   11    1     0
P04637   2    4     0     0
```

Comment: I believe(by seeing your attempt) you DO NOT want to consider line which starts from `>`, can you please confirm your last statement is not clear.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'|' '/^>/{val=$2;next} {print val,gsub(/[kK]/,""),gsub(/[rR]/,"")}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case you want to get output of headers too then try following.

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{print "       K R"}/^>/{val=$2;next} {print val,gsub(/[kK]/,""),gsub(/[rR]/,"")}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDT1:*** As per OP's comment in case we want to get count of 2 continous occurences of `KK` or `kk` then try following.

```
awk -F'|' '/^>/{val=$2;next} {print val,gsub(/kk|KK/,""),gsub(/rr|RR/,"")}' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** To get `k`,`kk`,`r`,`rr` counts use following.

```
awk -F'|' '/^>/{val=$2;next} {line=$0;print val,gsub(/[kK]/,""),gsub(/[rR]/,""),gsub(/kk|KK/,"",line),gsub(/rr|RR/,"",line)}' Input_file
```

***With headers:***

```
awk -F'|' '
BEGIN{
  print "       k/K\tr/R\tkk/KK\trr/RR"
}
/^>/{
  val=$2
  next
}
{
  line=$0
  print val,gsub(/[kK]/,""),gsub(/[rR]/,""),gsub(/kk|KK/,"",line),gsub(/rr|RR/,"",line)
}' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
       k/K      r/R     kk/KK   rr/RR
Q96A73  7       11      0       0
P13674  17      13      1       2
Q7Z4N8  11      11      0       1
P04637  2       4       0       0
```

Comment: what If I want to calculate the number of KK (means those that are K is close to K?) I am just wondering if I use your command, will I still be able to identify those ?

Comment: @Learner, sure then change `gsub(..)` mentioned in above to `gsub(/kk|KK/,"")` and let me know. It should take care of smalll `kk` and capital `KK`.

Comment: no , I meant counting those that have only two KK next to each other, should I do this ? `awk -F'|' '/^>/{val=$2;next} {print val,gsub(/[kK]/,""),gsub(/[rR]/,""),gsub(/[KK]/,"")}' Input_file` ??

Comment: @Learner, yes then use following one `awk -F'|' '/^>/{val=$2;next} {print val,gsub(/kk|KK/,""),gsub(/rr|RR/,"")}' Input_file` and let me know?

Comment: It gives me zero, I pasted the results of the output how it should be above, I really appreciate your guide

Comment: @Learner, please try my EDIT2 and let me know then?

Comment: it gives me 1awk: syntax error at source line 1 I` what could be the issue?

Comment: @Learner, EDIT2 and EDIT2: With headers: both are working fine for me, check once and let me know? NOt sure if it was copied properly?

Comment: anyway, you spent so much time although it does not solve it, I liked and accepted your answer. Thanks for your time, I will read about it tomorrow

Comment: @Learner, please elaborate more what is not working part? A solution should work on either small or large dataset, let me know on same.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl,

```
 perl -F"\|" -lne ' BEGIN{print "ID   K R"} s/(K|R)/$kv{$1}++/ge; if(not /^>/ ) { print "$x $kv{K} $kv{R}" ;%kv=() } $x=$F[1] '
```

with inputs

```
$ cat KR.txt
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL

$  perl -F"\|" -lne ' BEGIN{print "ID   K R"} s/(K|R)/$kv{$1}++/ge; if(not /^>/ ) { print "$x $kv{K} $kv{R}" ;%kv=() } $x=$F[1] ' KR.txt
ID   K R
Q96A73 8 11
P13674 17 13
Q7Z4N8 11 11
P04637 2 4

$
```

The OP has updated the question.. pls check now

```
$  perl -F"\|" -lne ' BEGIN{print "ID   K R"} if(not /^>/) { s/(K|R)/$kv{$1}++;$1/ge;s/(KK|RR)/$kv{$1}++/ige; print "$x $kv{K} $kv{R} ",$kv{KK}?$kv{KK}:0," ",$kv{RR}?$
kv{RR}:0 ;%kv=() } $x=$F[1] ' KR.txt
ID   K R
Q96A73 7 11 0 0
P13674 17 13 1 2
Q7Z4N8 11 11 0 1
P04637 2 4 0 0

$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t"; print "", "K", "R", "KK", "RR" }
    /^>/ { v=$2; next }
    { print v, gsub(/[kK]/,"&"), gsub(/[rR]/,"&"), gsub(/[kK]{2}/,"&"), gsub(/[rR]{2}/,"&") }
' file
        K       R       KK      RR
Q96A73  7       11      0       0
P13674  17      13      1       2
Q7Z4N8  11      11      0       1
P04637  2       4       0       0
```

Comment: @Ed Morton I wish you were my teacher ;-) how can I learn to code like you? I liked your answer already

Comment: In every situation - keep all your conditions positive and all the code simple. Beyond that just stick to the absolute basics of tight cohesion and loose coupling and the rest is gravy.